# Using firebase auth to register a user throws an error, but still registers correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a fairly sparse "register.html" page where I read in user email and password and register via `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. I have a `.then()` method attached, which does NOT get called. I also have a `.catch()` method attached, which DOES get called with an error that `user is not defined`.

First, `user is not defined` seems more appropriate for login, rather than registration. The whole point is to "define a new user!"

Secondly, I also have `.onAuthStateChanged` listener and that DOES show that the user status changes to logged in after registration.

Third, going to the firebase auth panel, I do see the newly created user!

Why is my `catch` block being called, and not the `then` block?

Here is my code:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .then(function(){
                     //user signed in
                    console.log('auth', user, 'registered');
                    if(location.href == document.referrer){
                        location.href = "/website/index.html";
                    }
                    else{ location.href = document.referrer; }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    $('#passwordAlert').show();
                    $('#passwordError').text(errorMessage);

                    console.log("Registeration failure:", username);
                    console.log('\t',errorCode);
                    console.log('\t',errorMessage);
                    //alert user
                });
```

Comment: Could you share both the error code and message?

Comment: The error message is “ user is not defined” and the error code is null.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The possible error codes are listed in the API docs.  It should be one of those.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=en#createuserwithemailandpassword

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when trying to answer this question [Firebase (web) - add user data upon signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228195/firebase-web-add-user-data-upon-signup/61228805#61228805)

The `.then` is not called because [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword)

> Creates a new user account associated with the specified email address and password.
>   On successful creation of the user account, **this user will also be signed in to your application.**

So "**this user will also be signed in to your application**". It will trigger the `.onAuthStateChanged` and for idk reason it just make `.then` won't be called anymore.

The `.catch` is called because [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) is not triggered, no sign-in or sign-out is occured

> After 4.0.0, the observer is only triggered on sign-in or sign-out.

Comment: This isn't correct.  `then()` should always be invoked if the call was successful, and `catch()` will always be invoked on failure.  It doesn't take into account any auth state listeners that might be attached.  Listeners just listen - they do not change the way any API works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a bit more logging, as someone requested. However, I'm now getting results I expect. I know I didn't change any logic, only `console.log` statements. However, the problem is now resolved. Not sure if this was a temporary glitch in firebase (probably unlikely) or an error on my part (although I didn't post the message until spending a couple of hours looking at my 177 line html/js page, looking through docs, etc.).

In any case, problem resolved.